# How to make contents like image to be shown only in our site?

Tags: php

I'm trying to make images in site to be shown only through our site using php content-type header to show the image.

i tried using a define which is defined in the index page and checked if it is defined, show the image in the php file which shows the image,

but when i use define it doesn't show the image but when i use a normal if statement, it works.

can this be fixed or is there another way to do?

```
if(defined("INDEX"))//the code i tried
{
    $file="1.jpg";

    $fileInfo=new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    $type=$fileInfo->file($file);

    header("content-type: $type");

    readfile($file);
}
else
{
    die("Access Denied");
}

if(1==1)//the simple if statement which works
{
    $file="1.jpg";

    $fileInfo=new finfo(FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

    $type=$fileInfo->file($file);

    header("content-type: $type");

    readfile($file);
}
else
{
    die("Access Denied");
}
```

The first block with define doesn't show the image and the define is defined in index page but second block with normal if statement works

Comment: if you defined a variable or constant in a different PHP script, it will not be available in this one, unless you `include()` or `require()` that other script in this one before you call `defined()`. But if "index" is a page, then that probably doesn't make much sense here. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve exactly...are you trying to stop other sites linking to your images? This is called "hotlinking" - if you google how to prevent that you'll find lots of info about how to do it (usually via a .htaccess rule or similar)

Comment: Thx for ur answer